# How to filter particular key from Map<String,Object> when key is flatjson

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting a response mentioned below.I want to filter keys having state only how can we do this thing

Example

```
 {

"response[0].id": 14,
"response[0].x": "ABCDED",
"response[0].y.code": "RERWRR",
"response[0].z.value": "TTTRRWW",

"response[1].id": 13,
"response[1].x": "RERERE",
"response[1].y.code": "TRTYUUU",
"response[1].z.value": "QWEAWE",

"response[2].id": 3,
"response[2].x": "POPOPO",
"response[2].y.code": "YUYUYU",
"response[2].z.value": "RUSUSUS",

"totalRecords": 3,
"limit": 100,
"offset": 0
}`
```

I only want to filter only response[0].x ,response[1].x  ,response[2].x   from Map

Comment: First of all: Why do you have such structure? What should be filtered? How should the result look like?

Comment: I guess, the expression `response[].x` returns a Collection?

Comment: Please read blogs like https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples /  https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-filtering. I think they would help

Answer (score 0):

as @Flown already mentioned, the structure of your json doesn't really look nice. Something like this would make more sense:

```
{
 "responses": [
   {
     "id": 3,
     "x": "ABC",
     "y": {
       "code": "CODE"
     },
     "z": {
       "value": "VALUE"
     }
   }, {
     ...
   }
 ],
  ...
}
```

Or even better if you could get rid of `x`, `y` and `z` and have something like that:

```
{
 "responses": [
   {
     "id": 3,
     "status": "STATUS",
     "code": "CODE"
     "value": "VALUE"
   }, {
     ...
   }
 ]
}
```

If you can't change the structure for whatever reason you could filter the map like that:

```java
Map<String, Object> filteredMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("].x")
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This returns you a `Map` only with entries where the key contains the string `]x.` which should be fine in your example (response[1 **].x** , response[2 **].x** , ...).

This should work but is still not really a nice solution. It would be better if you could change the json structure.